# AWT GraphicsConfig has coordinate issues when using multiple displays with different scale settings

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt

I am working on an application using JavaFx and embedding a few java AWT/Swing components with SwingNode. Recently I noticed some strange behavior when using multi display setup with different scaling on each display. Newly opened popups (i.e. context menu and combobox content popup) are misplaced.

The primary screen is defining the coordinate system and the other display to the left get negative coordinates. (see image below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIu4R.png

The top left coordinate of display 1 should be the same as the top right coordinate of display 2. But this is not the case.

[-1536,771] vs [-1920,964] for AWT and [-1920,443] vs [-1920,443] for javafx

We tracked the issue down to the awt-Win32GraphicsConfig getBounds method. As far as I understand the scaling for screen 1 (left display) is done on the absolute value for x/y. This results in the assumption that the next screen is working with the same scaling.

top left x value: -3840 (plattform x) / 1.25 (scaling factor) = -3072

with this x value and the width of 1536 we end up in the coordinate system of display 2 [-1920 to 0]

```
/*
 * Class:     sun_awt_Win32GraphicsConfig
 * Method:    getBounds
 * Signature: ()Ljava/awt/Rectangle
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
    Java_sun_awt_Win32GraphicsConfig_getBounds(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisobj,
                                               jint screen)
{
    jclass clazz;
    jmethodID mid;
    jobject bounds = NULL;

    clazz = env->FindClass("java/awt/Rectangle");
    CHECK_NULL_RETURN(clazz, NULL);
    mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "(IIII)V");
    if (mid != 0) {
        RECT rRW = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        Devices::InstanceAccess devices;
        AwtWin32GraphicsDevice *device = devices->GetDevice(screen);

        if (TRUE == MonitorBounds(AwtWin32GraphicsDevice::GetMonitor(screen), &rRW)) {

            int x = (device == NULL) ? rRW.left : device->ScaleDownX(rRW.left);
            int y = (device == NULL) ? rRW.top  : device->ScaleDownY(rRW.top);
            int w = (device == NULL) ? rRW.right - rRW.left
                                     : device->ScaleDownX(rRW.right - rRW.left);
            int h = (device == NULL) ? rRW.bottom - rRW.top
                                     : device->ScaleDownY(rRW.bottom - rRW.top);

            bounds = env->NewObject(clazz, mid, x, y, w, h);

        }
        else {
            // 4910760 - don't return a null bounds, return the bounds of the
            // primary screen
            int w = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
            int h = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

            bounds = env->NewObject(clazz, mid,
                                    0, 0,
                                    device == NULL ? w : device->ScaleDownX(w),
                                    device == NULL ? h : device->ScaleDownY(h));
        }
        if (safe_ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
           return 0;
        }
    }
    return bounds;
}
```

Any ideas to work around this problem?

Comment: which java/fx version? Faintly remember that there had been issues with hidpi monitors that I think have been fixed (though not certain ;)

Comment: openjdk 11 // openjfx 13